# I do not understand about bitwise operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, bitwise-operators

I am student studying programming.

As far as I know, Javascript saves number as float.

However, bitwise operator in Javascript run as a type of number is integer.

For instance,

```
> 1 | 2 // -> 3
> 2 << 4 // -> 32
```

How is it possible?

I find official documentation(mdn web docs), but I can not find the reason.

Comment: Honestly this is the kind of thing you can learn from books or online resources about the programming language.

Comment: Here's an app that might help: [Visualizing Bitwise Operations](https://7io9he.csb.app/)

Comment: _“As far as I know, JavaScript saves number as float.”_ — And now you know that this was an oversimplification.

Comment: [_Despite the fact that all numbers in JavaScript are floating-point, the bitwise operators require numeric operands that have integer values. They operate on these integer operands using a 32-bit integer representation instead of the equivalent floating-point representation._](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch05s08.html)

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise operators in JavaScript convert numbers to 32-bit integers before performing the operation. This means that even though JavaScript saves numbers as floats, the bitwise operators treat them as 32-bit integers. This is why you are able to use the bitwise operators on numbers and get integer results.

Comment: Thanks. Then I have one question more. In C, I do `a << 2` instead of `a * 4` due to program's speed. is `a << 2` faster than `a * 4` in Javascript too?

Comment: @csh Yes, using the left shift operator << is generally faster than multiplication * in JavaScript too. This is because bitwise operations, like left shift, are low-level operations that can be directly executed by the CPU, while multiplication involves more complex operations that are typically implemented in software.

Comment: @rviretual_001 While in most/many cases modern general purpose CPUs have integrated FPU support, shift operations require two additional conversion steps over multiplication - convert operands to unsigned integers before the shift operation, and convert integer results back into 64 bit FP format to store as a number in JavaScript. A quick test on my current laptop showed  multiplication by 4 was about 66% faster than left shifting integer values by 2 bits in Firefox JS.

Answer (score 1):

As @rviretural_001 mentioned, JavaScript does some automatic conversions by spec. For example, in addition to IEEE 754 doubles to 32 signed integers:

```js
0 == '0' // true
```

String to Integer (Shift Right)

```js
'4' >> 1 // 2
```

Converting to Integer (Bitwise OR)

```js
'1.3' | 0 // 1
```

This last one was used in [asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) for 32 signed integers

Answer (score 0):

just to contribute to the answers above note that the conversion of a floating-point number to an integer is done by removing the fractional part of the number.

For example, if you have the number 4.5 and you use a bitwise operator on it, JavaScript will convert it to the integer 4 before performing the operation.

This tutorial might help you to find out more https://www.programiz.com/javascript/bitwise-operators

Also note that performing bitwise operations on floating-point numbers can lead to unexpected results. This is due to the way floating-point numbers are represented in memory. So, it's recommended to avoid using bitwise operators on floating-point numbers in JavaScript.